# How can I check if a variable starts with a range of letters such as A-G or H-Z?

Tags: velocity

How can I check if a variable starts with a range of letters such as A-G or H-Z?

I'm currently using this that works:

```
#elseif($h == 'A' || $h == 'B'|| $h == 'C'|| $h == 'D'|| $h == 'E'|| $h == 'F'|| $h == 'G')
```

But I would like to clean it up to something like this:

```
#elseif($h == 'A-G')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on a regular expression.

```
#elseif($h.matches("^[A-G].*$")) ...
```